How can I return a single button?
The following code sucessfully targets all elements with .btn class.
$(".btn").toggleClass("pressed");

Meanwhile, this returns the first element with .btn class.
$(".btn")[0];

But why $(".btn")[0].toggleClass("pressed"); doesn't work and return ".toggleClass is not a function in console."?

The answer is in your question: "this returns the first element with .btn class".

How aboput the jQuery documentation ?.. eq method ... quote ... "Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .eq() method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that set."

Also .first()

this code returns only the DOM element, not the jquery object
$(".btn")[0].toggleClass("pressed");

but if you want to toggle the class on the first specific button you should use this:
$($(".btn")[0]).toggleClass("pressed");


While possible, this isn't best practice, when .first() and .eq(0) already exist.
